# OpenGL - Most efficient way to update model info (e.g. model matrix)

Tags: c++, opengl

So lets say I have abstracted OpenGL's general buffer object workflow into a Model class. All I need to do for a 3D model to appear in the OpenGL context is to initialise a Model object, add it to a container, and draw all Models in the container to in the render loop.
Lets say I have 1000 Models in my scene. The way in which I set a model's global coordinates now becomes very important.

I know of a couple of ways I can go about updating Model info such as its model matrix. One would be sharing one shader program for every model, and using glUniformMatrix4fv to set the model matrix for the shader just before drawing each Model in the render loop. Another way would be for each Model object to contain its own shader program, and the model matrix for that shader is set upon initialisation of the Model object. Then, in the render loop, glUseProgram is used for each Models shader program just before it is drawn.

What is the most efficient way of going about updating Model info such as its model matrix (as I feel as if my currently known methods are extremely inefficient)?

Comment: There are advanced methods for passing data to shaders if you are on a modern GPU: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object, https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is somewhat general, I'll keep the answer general as well.

In general, changing state between OpenGL draw calls is costly so best performance is achieved by minimizing state changes. However, not all state changes are equal. An exhaustive list of which state changes are more costly than others is not really possible because their cost changes between vendors, driver versions, etc. A good understanding of the complete OpenGL pipeline and how computer hardware works can provide an intuition of which code paths are better. It is also really helpful to read Nvidia and AMD presentations (from GDC, Siggraph, etc.) that focus on optimizing graphical engine performances.

For the specific question you asked, it will most likely be much slower to use different shaders each containing their own matrix than sharing a single shader and setting the matrix in a uniform value before each draw call. Changing the active shader requires much more work by the driver to reconfigure the GPU pipeline than simply writing 16 floats to GPU memory. There are also other techniques that would allow you to store all your matrices in a single buffer and issue a single draw call with all your models if they use the same shader.

One way is to have all matrices in an array in a single SSBO or UBO. Then each mesh has an index that indicates which matrix it should use. The index could come from a vertex attribute (like the w component of the vertex position).

Comment: which techniques are those?